# Ex Occulto Unitas — is that the correct syntax for a motto?

Tags: translation-check, motto

I have little knowledge of Latin grammar — and few resources in Japan. I am attempting to create a fictional agency in a novel and its accompanying motto: From Secrecy, Unity.

My attempted translation is "Ex Occulto Unitas". I used a few "Ex (X) (X)" mottos as a pattern, using the ablative tense of the masculine 1st/2nd dec OCCULTUS to match the away from image of 'EX'. I'm unsure if it should stay masculine or if it should change to feminine or neuter.

I am much less confident on what tense UNITAS should be in. I assume it should be the Nominative?

Answer (score 3):

The adjective *occultus* means "hidden", "secret", and other such things.
It is normal to use the neuter *occultum* for "secrecy" or "a secret thing", and this meaning is listed separately in some dictionaries.
The word *occultum* should be in neuter, but in ablative it looks just like masculine.
Therefore I think your word choices for "secrecy" and "unity" are perfect.

The pattern "*ex* X(abl) Y(nom)" for "Y from X" is very common in Latin.
(Latin word order is different from English, so the translation "from X, Y" feels a little forced to me, but it is a matter of taste. And this question concerns Latin, so the English phrasing is tangential.)
Thus *ex occulto unitas* is a great translation of your motto.
It also has the added benefit of being understandable to many who don't know much Latin.